# CSS weird behaviour

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a website and have some h3 headers and paragraphs that are wrapped in a div class named "featured-info".
Also i have a footer element that is in the main wrapper in the body.
The paragraphs are put in italic:

```
.featured-info p {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

and the footer has a border:

```
footer {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

Also the footer text is a h4 uppercased:

```
footer h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The main problem is that i have a setting:
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) that makes some navigation buttons inline and resizes some text but...
when the page size is smaller than 750px the footer styling and the italic font dissapears... and i don't understand why. i will provide more info if is needed. thx!

LE: found it. a damn semi-colon. THANK YOU ALL! didn't expect to get so many responses in such a short time.

now i got another problem

under the menu which changes when the resolution is min 750px i have a h1 header that is usually on center

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2.4213em; /*3.3684em*/
    line-height: 1.2656em;
    margin-top: 0.4219em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color:  rgb(172, 140, 71);
    text-align: center;

}
```

the problem is it gets to to the right when the window is from 750px to 950px. I have these settings:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px){

    .main-navigation {
        min-height: 90px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(36,36,36);
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(36,36,36);
        /*overflow: hidden;  dubiosssss */
    }

    .main-navigation ul {
        max-width: 950px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    .main-navigation li {
        float:left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 20%;

    }

    .main-navigation a {
        background: none;
    }
}
 /* media query for 750*/
}
@media screen and (min-width: 950px){

    .main-navigation ul {
        position: relative;
        right: -15px;
    }

}
```

any advice would be great, thanks again!

Comment: yes: more info needed if you want any useful answer (HTML, CSS)

Comment: Well, if that styling is happening within your media query it would make sense the styling would disappear when the screen is < 750px.

Comment: Check if your curly braces match or if you accidentally have one in the wrong place which could lead to your media query including more style rules than you think

Comment: If the entire footer only contains h4 content you don't need 2 style rules for it: just have **footer{…:…:…}** to be descriptive, and to help with debugging - like this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min-width in a @media parameter means that any size from the size you specified and larger will get the styles that you set.

It sounds like you have some of your styles are put in the wrong place. It is usually better to start small and go large in your CSS. This means specify global styles (styles that won't change) first and then work your way up to large viewports.

You are probably overwriting some styles that you would like to keep.